# How to pass second viewcontroller textfield value to first viewcontroller array and dismiss when button tapped in swift4

Tags: arrays, swift, dismiss

I have two view controllers, i want to send second viewcontroller textfield value to first viewcontroller array and dismiss the second view controller when button tapped.

here is my code:

in firstVC:

i have created array:

```
var iteamsArr = [String]()
```

in secondVC:

```
class CreatePopUpViewController: UIViewController {


var popData: String?
var createBussnss = CreateBusinessViewController()// is my firstVC name
@IBOutlet weak var addTf: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@IBAction func saveButn(_ sender: Any) {

  createBussnss.iteamArray.append(addTf.text!)

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

}
```

here viewcontroller is dismissing but but values are not added to arry in the first viewcontroller
please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a delegate.

```
protocol CreatePopUpDelegate: class {
     func createPopUpDidSaveTextFieldPick(_ value: String)
}
```

Then in first view controller:

```
extension FirstViewController: CreatePopUpDelegate {
    func createPopUpDidSaveTextFieldPick(_ value: String) {
        print ("first view controller now has value of textfield")
        // add it to array or whatever
}
```

Then in second view controller:

```
class CreatePopUpViewController: UIViewController, MyDelegate {
    weak var delegate: CreatePopUpDelegate?

@IBAction func saveButn(_ sender: Any) {

    createBussnss.iteamArray.append(addTf.text!)

    delegate?.createPopUpDidSaveTextFieldPick(addTf.text!)
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

}

somewhere in the code you just have to do:

```
secondViewController.delegate = firstViewController.
```

In this type of scenarios, the `secondViewController` is instantiated and presented from the `firstViewController`, so you would just do:

```
secondViewController.delegate = self
```

---

Also, as a general piece of advice, ready the Code Guidelines for Swift. In Swift, longer clearer names are preferred.

Instead of `saveButn`, do `saveButton`.

Instead of `addTf`, do `addTextField`.

Instead of `createBussnss`, do `createBussiness`

Also avoid doing `!`, better do `guard let text = textField.text else { return`.

Good luck!
 It's clearer, better code.

Comment: Thank you so much it really helpful, i have upvoted and accepted your answer, but i am very new to swift, i have one doubt.. where should i create CreatePopUpDelegate

Comment: `CreatePopUpDelegate` can be created anywhere. Above the definition of any of your classes, or anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can use delegate to communicate between two controllers, well now in swift we can even use closures for same.
You need to declare an handler in second ViewController like:

`var saveButtonHandler = ((_ handler: String?) -> Void)`

In FirstViewController where you will be pushing the controller you can define this handler like

`secondViewController.saveButtonHandler = { (text:String) in
     //append your text here to array

 }`

and on save button click

`self.saveButtonHandler?(<Your_Text>)`

Comment: Just make sure only to use the `String` inside the handler, don't use the button or any variables of the `secondViewController`. You can fall in a retain-cycle.